What happens when a helicopter loses the engine and autorotation is not initiated?
I am thinking of a very basic main and tail rotor configuration helicopter, without any aerodynamic surfaces like vertical or horizontal stabilizer, in a steady state horizontal forward flight at cruise speed. Now the engine fails completely and no one touches the controls. How does the helicopter crash?
My thoughts:

Obviously: Rotor RPM decreases ⟶ Thrust decreases ⟶ Acceleration downwards ⟶ Sink rate
Autorotation will not happen, as collective would have to be decreased to maintain RPM and get rotor to autorotation state.
The helicopter starts spinning as the tail rotor still produces lift, but there is no torque by the engine which would have to be compensated (however, the airflow around the fuselage stabilizes the direction?)


Welcome to Aviation SE, Aron!  A good first question... no obvious answers online, not even NTSB reports.  My guess: sink rate increases so quickly that nothing else matters before impact, unless you start much higher than helis usually fly.  If air drag or mechanical drag slows the rotor enough, it may eventually tumble randomly.

If the engine fails, will the rotor be "free running", or will it be blocked? And how can the tail rotor produce "lift"?

If you don't lower collective, the blades slow down and stall and the machine becomes a falling rock, with the rotor eventually slowing to a stop if there is enough time to ground contact. Yaw will depend on tail rotor pitch, and how fast it is spinning, with maybe a bit of yawing moment from bearing drag of the rotor mast between the sprag clutch and transmission housing, to the extent the rotor is still turning. Otherwise you're just a falling object.
If you do lower collective but do nothing to maintain forward airspeed, it should autorotate vertically. You'll hit the ground pretty hard, probably break your back, but may live.
There have been autogryos with special landing gear that can absorb high descent rates, and these can autorotate vertically to land.

If high enough, would the rotor eventually rotate in the opposite direction, eventually doing what an auto-rotate setting would cause (earlier and in the other direction)?

@U.Windl Helicopter blades are airfoils with a round leading edge and a sharp trailing edge. The trailing edge cannot guide a laminar airflow around the top of the blade, and the round edge cannot completely keep from doing the same thing, inducing a stall somewhere on the top of the blade, no matter what. As such, airfoils, and hence Helicopter blades, simply have no appreciable performance when moving in reverse.

Curious, which helicopter has this high impact landing gears you mentioned?

@Gabe Not helicopter, autogyro. A guy designed a very long stroke landing gear for a small open single seat gyrocopter. He could stop it in flight and descend straight to the ground and the gear could soak up the touchdown. It didn't catch on and you don't see it around much (may have been just too tippy on the ground to be practical). Root around on youtube and you should be able to find a vid.

Could yaw inputs affect the speed of a vertical descent?  What kind of yaw input would minimize it?  I'd expect a situation similar to a dome parachute, where there's an optimal amount of air to allow through the middle to ensure the parachute doesn't push down too much air below it.

Once the main rotor stalls, you have effectively no yaw control.  The tail rotor is geared to a higher RPM than the main rotor, but still has to be turning at a significant rate to produce any lift force (in the yaw direction) with its blades.
